# How to complete a bash function with multiple parameters/options?

Tags: bash, code-completion

I defined a function alias for a command: `aa` and I defined a `_complete_aa` function which is used as a suggestion for the `aa` command via `complete -F _complete_aa aa` (See code below)

```
aa(){
    anothercommand ${@}
}

_complete_aa(){
    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "clean build start" "${COMP_WORDS[1]}"))
}

complete -F _complete_aa aa
```

When I use the function I have an unexpected behavior:

When I type `aa cle` and press `TAB` the prompt correctly completes my input into `aa clean`

But, when I type `aa clean bui` and press `TAB`, the prompt completes my inuput into `aa clean clean`, while I expect it should change into `aa clean build`.

I guess my error is in the below completion function, Which does not take care of the index of the current word under completion.

```
_complete_aa(){
    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "clean build start" "${COMP_WORDS[1]}"))
}
```

Question: how I should change the body of the `_complete_aa` function so that I get completion of the current word into `clean build start` for each new option/parameter I am typing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The completion function gets positional parameters, of which `$2` is the "word being completed", so you could do this:

```sh
_complete_aa(){
    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "clean build start" "$2"))
}
```

If your completion really is just the selection of given words, you can use the simpler `-W` completion instead:

```sh
complete -W 'clean build start' aa
```

Comment: Awesome. Clear explaination, and both the proposed solutions works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Index `COMP_WORDS` with current word index.

```
aa() {
    anothercommand "$@"
}

_complete_aa() {
    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "clean build start" "${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}"))
}

complete -F _complete_aa aa
```

The `"${COMP_WORDS[1]}"` is always going to be the first word after the command.

Comment: Also this solution works. This solution goes more in the details, and it is more useful in case one wants to write a complex function that deals with the current position of the word.